# What is the JavaScript equivalent of C#'s HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode?

Tags: javascript, httpserverutility

In **JavaScript**, how can i decode a string that was encoded in C# using `HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode`?

There are some equivalents in other languages but i couldn't rewrite them in JS. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the [**Java**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21657244/4582649) version.

This is the [**Objective-C**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30415441/4582649) version.

### Update:

C#'s `URLTokenEncode` is not the same as base64 encoding. For example the last character is always the number of padding characters. So some characters need to be replaced properly. Java and Objective-C version of the code show which characters need to be replaced with what.

I tried `decodeURIComponent` but it was not decoded successfully. That makes sense because the string is encoded by a particular method. It's not base64.

For example, This is just a part of a C#'s `UrlTokenEncode` String:

`vj4_fv7__7-_Pr6-ff3_Pr6_vz8_________________f____79_vP1_vb3_vz8____________________AAA1`

And this is the correct decoded version using Objective-C/Java method:

`vj4/fv7//7+/Pr6+ff3/Pr6/vz8/////////////////f////79/vP1/vb3/vz8////////////////////AAA=`

Comment: [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)

Comment: Please see my update @Tushar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to convert the [Objective-c version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30415441/4582649) of `URLTokenDecode` by [Jeffrey Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1298400/jeffery-thomas) to JavaScript and it worked.

**Here is the function:**

```
function URLTokenDecode(token) {

    if (token.length == 0) return null;

    // The last character in the token is the number of padding characters.
    var numberOfPaddingCharacters = token.slice(-1);

    // The Base64 string is the token without the last character.
    token = token.slice(0, -1);

    // '-'s are '+'s and '_'s are '/'s.
    token = token.replace(/-/g, '+');
    token = token.replace(/_/g, '/');

    // Pad the Base64 string out with '='s
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfPaddingCharacters; i++)
        token += "=";

    return token;
}
```

**Here is the $filter if you are using AngularJS:**

```
app.filter('URLTokenDecode', function () {
        return function (token) {

            if (token.length == 0) return null;

            // The last character in the token is the number of padding characters.
            var numberOfPaddingCharacters = token.slice(-1);

            // The Base64 string is the token without the last character.
            token = token.slice(0, -1);

            // '-'s are '+'s and '_'s are '/'s.
            token = token.replace(/-/g, '+');
            token = token.replace(/_/g, '/');

            // Pad the Base64 string out with '='s
            for (var i = 0; i < numberOfPaddingCharacters; i++)
                token += "=";

            return token;
        }

});
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be correct.  You're missing out on the "int equalsCount = (int)(((char)bytes[inputLength]) - 0x30);"

Comment: @Stefan, because of how str.replace() works in Javascript, i don't need to know the length of my input. That goes the same when i'm padding with '=', no need to know the length. So this should work.

Comment: Can't really say I understand why anybody does it this way instead of just url-encoding a base-64 encoding, or what's the logic behind this method, but anyway, it would surprise me if this decoding method would work correctly IN ALL CASES. Note that while it may work correctly in a few cases, this doesn't necessarely mean it works correctly for all cases.

Comment: @StefanSteiger, I'm sending a binary image from my webservice and if i send it with Base64 encoding then in some cases it sends empty. But UrlTokenEncode works with the same case. So that's why i'm using this. About this method , I'd say it should work because it does what the algorithm says. I'd be surprised if it doesn't work in all cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sobhan - I wasted a lot of time converting to hex then modify (with no exact solution) - until I found your solution

Answer (score 0):

I guess that would be decodeuricomponent:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp

To decode a UTF8-base64-encoded string in JavaScript:

```
var str2 = decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob(b64)));
console.log(str2);
```

To encode a UTF8-JavaScript-string as such in JavaScript:

```
var str = "äöüÄÖÜçéèñ";
var b64 = window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(str)))
console.log(b64);
```

Seems UrlTokenDecode is a little bit more complicated. 
The best method to be 100% sure is to call UrlTokenDecode on the server-side with AJAX, then return a simple base64-encoded string.

```
public static byte[] UrlTokenDecode (string input)
{
    if (input == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException ("input");
    if (input.Length < 1)
        return new byte[0];
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (input);
    int inputLength = input.Length - 1;
    int equalsCount = (int)(((char)bytes[inputLength]) - 0x30);
    char[] ret = new char[inputLength + equalsCount];
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < inputLength; i++) {
        switch ((char)bytes[i]) {
            case '-':
                ret[i] = '+';
                break;

            case '_':
                ret[i] = '/';
                break;

            default:
                ret[i] = (char)bytes[i];
                break;
        }
    }
    while (equalsCount > 0) {
        ret[i++] = '=';
        equalsCount--;
    }

    return Convert.FromBase64CharArray (ret, 0, ret.Length);
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpServerUtility.cs)

Comment: this would not work because my string is not a base64 encoded string. It's encoded in C# using `URLTokenEncode` which is a bit different than base 64. Please see my update. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Stefan, but i have the limitation that the string i'm sending from server-side should always be UrlTokenEncoded because if it's encoded by Base64 then in some cases it doesn't work. So i have to decode it client-side.

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly against the posting rules as its not an answer to the question but, I found this page whilst looking for the `UrlTokenEncode` method (not decode) so using the info here I made the following method which I hope helps someone else out:

```
function urlTokenEncode(str) {
    var b64 = btoa(encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g,
            function(match, t) {
                return String.fromCharCode('0x' + t);
            })),
        padChars = b64.match(/=/g);
    return b64.replace(/=/g, "") + (padChars == null ? 0 : padChars.length);
}
```

Tested and working with C# `HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode` and `HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode`

Answer (score -1):

read this artical in MDN which describes the problem & solution:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

```
function b64EncodeUnicode(str) {
    return btoa(encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g, function(match, p1) {
        return String.fromCharCode('0x' + p1);
    }));
}

b64EncodeUnicode('✓ à la mode'); // "4pyTIMOgIGxhIG1vZGU="
```

Comment: this would not work because my string is not a base64 encoded string. It's encoded in C# using `URLTokenEncode` which is a bit different than base64. Please see my update. Thanks.